# jquery Datepicker, set default date to value of a span

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

If I do `alert($(this).parents().find("span:first").html())` it displays `03/28/2011`

If I view the source code `<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_StDt">03/28/2011</span>`

If I set defaultDate within the datepicker

```
defaultDate: new Date($(this).parents().find("span:first").html()),
```

It defaults to 12/31/1969

**EDIT**
With the help of vtortola's solution below, I got it.  I needed to parse the date and check for an empty span.

```
        var myDate = null;
        var minDate = null;
        $(".StartDateImg").datepicker({
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                myDate = null;
                if ($(this).parents().find("span:first").html().length > 1) {
                    myDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $(this).parents().find("span:first").html());
                    $(this).parents().find("input:first").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', myDate);

                }
                minDate = null;
                if ($(this).parents().closest('tr').find('td:last').length > 1) {
                    minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $(this).parents().closest('tr').find('td:last').html())
                    $(this).parents().find("input:first").datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
                }
            },
            duration: '',
            showTime: false,
            constrainInput: false,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                $(this).parents().find("span")[0].innerHTML = dateText;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with :

```
 defaultDate:  $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $(this).parents().find("span:first").text())
```

Cheers.

Comment: That defaults to the current date.

Comment: $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy',stringDate) definitely parse the date you put in stringDate, so probably you have something else wrong. Are you sure that the content of that SPAN is plain text and not HTML ?

Comment: If I view the source, I see `<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_StDt">03/28/2011</span>
`

Comment: When I click on it now, before the calendar displays, I get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'setHours'"